Lowest frequency item in a Zipf distribution sample
I am trying to use Markov chain to model LFU cache operation. Users requests contents that follow Zipf distribution. The cache size is $n$. There are ${N \choose n}$ number of states, with each state representing one combination of all possible object sets in the the cache. I am trying to create the transition matrix, P.
I am having trouble finding the probability that a given object has the least frequency in the cache.

What have you tried? How will you deal with equal frequencies in the sample? How will you deal with objects which do not appear.

I am trying a small case, with n=2 and simple distribution p1 = 0.2 and p2 = 0.8. Let X1 be a random variable showing the number of times that x1 (object) has been sampled, similary X2 another random variable showing the number of times that x2 has been sampled. Question: P(X1>=X2). Thank you

OK.  So in your example, $P(X_1=2,X_2=0)=0.64, P(X_1=1,X_2=1)=0.32$ and $P(X_1=0,X_2=2)=0.04$.  You then get $P(X_1 \ge X_2)=0.96$.  Just for my understanding, are you saying that "2" has the lowest relative frequency in the sample with probability $0.96$, even though you are certain either  it does not appear at all in the sample or it appears with the same frequency as "1" (or it appears more often than "1")?

Let me give you the entire problem: I am trying to model LFU cache operation using Markov chain. Users request contents that follow a discrete distribution. The cache size is I am trying to use Markov chain to model LFU cache operation. Users requests contents that follow Zipf distribution. The cache size is . There are ${N \choose n}$ number of states with each state representing one combination of all possible set of objects in the cache. I am trying to create the transition matrix, P.  I can't find the probability that a given object in the cache has the least frequent value.
